# How to access the SparkSession from the worker?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

I'm using spark structured streaming in databricks. In that, I'm using foreach operation to perform some operations on every record of the data. But the function which I'm passing in foreach uses SparkSession but it's throwing an error: _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers.

So, Is there any way to use SparkSession inside foreach?

EDIT #1:
One example of function passed in foreach would be something like:

```py
def process_data(row):
  df = spark.createDataFrame([row])    
  df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("T2")
  spark.sql("""
    MERGE INTO T1
    USING T2 ON T2.type="OrderReplace" AND T1.ReferenceNumber=T2.originalReferenceNumber
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      shares = T2.shares,
      price = T2.price,
      ReferenceNumber = T2.newReferenceNumber
  """)
```

So, I need SparkSession here which is not available inside foreach.

Comment: You can access the Spark session only in the driver. But in almost every case a solution can be found to run the required calculation in another way

Comment: In my case, I've streaming data and on that data, I want to run foreach loop so as to get data row by row and then perform a bunch of operations on each row individually and these operations require SparkSession. But I found that the code inside the foreach is run on worker node ,so not able to access SparkSession there...So what I'm supposed to do here?

Comment: You should try to describe the operations you want to perform on each row.

Comment: I need to update another table(say T1) based on this row. So basically, I'm creating a spark dataframe of this single row, then saving this dataframe as table (say T2) and then want to run SQL queries(Insert/Delete/Merge Into etc.) which will update T1 based on the data in T2.

Comment: One example of function passed in foreach would be something like:
 `def process_data(row):
    df = spark.createDataFrame([row])
    df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("T2")
    spark.sql("""MERGE INTO T1 USING T2 ON T2.type="OrderReplace" AND T1.ReferenceNumber=T2.originalReferenceNumber WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET shares = T2.shares, price=T2.price,ReferenceNumber=T2.newReferenceNumber""")`
So, I need SparkSession here which is not available inside foreach.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the tasks you want to perform row by row on your streaming dataset, you can try using [foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch).

A streaming dataset may have thousands to millions of records and if you are hitting external systems on each record, it is a massive overhead. From your example, it seems you are updating a base data set `T1` based on events in `T2`.

From the link above, you can do something like below,

```
def process_data(df, epoch_id):    
  df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("T2")
  spark.sql("""
    MERGE INTO T1
    USING T2 ON T2.type="OrderReplace" AND T1.ReferenceNumber=T2.originalReferenceNumber
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      shares = T2.shares,
      price = T2.price,
      ReferenceNumber = T2.newReferenceNumber
  """)

streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_data).start()
```

Some additional points regarding what you are doing,

1. You are trying to do a foreach on a streaming data set and overwriting `T2` hive table. Since records are processed parallel in clusters-managers like `yarn`, there might be a corrupted T2 since multiple tasks maybe updating it.
2. If you are persisting records in T2 (even temporarily), why don't you try making the merge/ update logic as a separate batch process? This will be similar to the `foreachBatch` solution I wrote above.
3. Updating/ Creating Hive tables fire a map/reduce job ultimately which requires resource negotiations, etc., etc. and may be painfully slow if done on each record, you may want to consider a different type of destination like a JDBC based one for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem with foreachBatch is that if I've multiple source rows matching with same target row, then it throws the error in merge operation